# Python program - Help pairing elements together without using a dictionary

Tags: python

I"m studying for my Intro Python class and I have a proficiency exam tomorrow. In the sample problem, it asks:

`"Write a program in Python to list the students who are members of the most
frequent major (assume there is only one most frequently occurring major). Your program should ask the user to input the number of students to be entered, and then ask for the name and major (you don’t know which majors will be entered ahead of time) for each of those students, on separate lines. The most frequent of the majors should be determined, and the names of the students from the most frequently occurring major should then be displayed (in any order you wish). In the following example, the user is inputting data.
How many students? 5
Enter Student Name
sue
enter major
CS
Enter Student Name
bob
enter major
PE
Enter Student Name
tom
enter major
CS
Enter Student Name
jack
enter major
CS
Enter Student Name
mary
enter major
MTH
Most Frequent Major is: CS
sue
tom
jack`

So, I started to write my program, but unfortunately I'm stuck. I figured out a complicated method of gathering the majors together and finding sorting them. With that, it's easy to display the most frequent major. However, I can't seem to figure out how to assign the name values to each major. I know a dictionary cannot be used because they are immutable. Given my code, what function can I use to assign each name to a major?

```
num_students = int(input("enter the number of students: "))
counter = 0

major_list = []
name_list = []

while counter < num_students:
    name = input("Enter Student Name: ")
    name_list.append(name)

    major = input("enter major: ").upper
    major_list.append(major)

    counter += 1

major_counter = {}

for word in major_list:
    if word in major_counter:
        major_counter[word] += 1

    else:
        major_counter[word] = 1

popular_majors = sorted(major_counter, key = major_counter.get, reverse = True)
top_major = popular_majors[0]

print("Most Frequent Mjaor is: ", top_major)

input("Press Enter to exit")
```

I'm really hung up on this one. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task is to display a list of the students in the most frequent major. Your code does not keep track of the student names, but you need to if you are to include them in the output.

A dictionary of lists is a good way to go. As you have done, use the major as the key but, instead of counting the number of students, add each student to a list. Once you have completed collecting the user's input, you can find the most common major and print out its students. Something like this:

```
major_students = {}
for major, student in zip(major_list, name_list):
    if major not in major_students:
        major_students[major] = []
    major_students[major].append(student)
```

In the above I have retained your method of collecting the user input into two lists which I then [zipped](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) together for processing. It's better though if you insert the user's input directly into the `major_students` dict as it is entered:

```
major_students = {}
for i in range(num_students):
    name = input("Enter Student Name: ")
    major = input("enter major: ").upper()
    major_students[major] = major_students.get(major, []) + [name]
```

This results in a dictionary with the major as key and a list of students as values. Next, finding the major with the most students can be done by sorting the dictionary items using the length of the student list:

```
major, students = sorted(major_students.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True)[0]

print("Most Frequent Major is {} with {} students: {}".format(major, len(students), ', '.join(students)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I your goal is to pair two elements together without dictionaries. I would:

```
>>> array = []
```

Create an array.

```
>>> array.append(["name","major"])
```

Then create a sub array with your two values

> > > print array
> > >           [['name', 'major']]

See how there is a array within a array?

> > > array.append(["tom","CS"])
> > >       print array

How add your stuff!

```
[['name', 'major'], ['tom', 'CS']]
```

And here is our end result!